# I need to concatenate two vectors same dimension but different shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `y` of size `4 x 1` , and another vector `y2` of size `4 x 1` too, I  concatenated  the vectors `y` and real and imaginary parts of `y2` and got two different vectors with same dimension but different shape ! . . I don't know what's the difference between both them.

For example, here is the first code:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.random.randn(4, 4) + 1j * np.random.randn(4, 4)
x = np.array([[1 + 1j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j]])
y = h @ x
n = 3
y2 = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for ii in range(n):
    y2[: , ii] = np.linalg.pinv(h[: , ii].reshape(-1,1)).dot(y)
y_con = np.concatenate((np.real(y2),np.imag(y2)))
y_m = np.absolute(y)
Y3 = np.concatenate([y_con.reshape(-1,1), y_m])
```

So, in this case, the output `Y3` is a vector of dimension `12 x 1` when I check its shape, it's `(12,1)`

now, let's run the code in another way:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.random.randn(4, 4) + 1j * np.random.randn(4, 4)
x = np.array([[1 + 1j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j]])
y = h @ x

y2 = np.linalg.pinv(h).dot(y)
y_con = np.concatenate((np.real(y2),np.imag(y2)))
y_m = np.absolute(y)
Y3 = np.concatenate([y_con, y_m])
```

In this case, `Y3` is a vector of dimension `12,` when I check its shape, it's `(12,)`

First I don't know what's the difference between the two vectors in their shape? .. and what I want is to use the first code to get a code of dimension of (12,) instead of (12,1)? how can I do that ?

Comment: You can use `reshape` to add or remove a dimension.  `...reshape(-1,1)` makes a (n,1) array, regardless of what the original shape was (as long as there were `n` elements).  `....reshape(-1)` will make (n,) shape.  `np.ravel` also makes a 1d array.  `arr[:,None]` is another way of adding a dimension, so is `arr[None,:]`.  As long as you don't try to change the total number of elements you can reshape all kinds of ways, even `arr.reshape([1, -1, 1, 1])` to make a 4d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a "column" vector which is 2-dimensional. Just add `.flatten()` to the end of the last line in your first code to make a 1-dimensional "row" vector.